# MS Access Backend Controls - Close, Save etc

Tags: user-interface, ms-access, controls, split

This may be a simple fix and maybe I'm missing something obvious, but when I split my DB it wasn't entirely finished, and there have been modifications requested which require me to edit my backend.

How come it's not the same GUI layout (exactly)? Tables open in "windows" within Access, and when maximized, cannot be closed, etc. It's annoying as hell as I can't close my table to deal with its relations. I can only get to design view by finding it in the Tables list and RightClick->Design instead of on the bar above the tables, etc.

Is there a setting somewhere that caused these minor GUI changes when I split the DB? How do I put it back, as it's bugging me greatly; slowing down modifications by a lot.

EDIT: It seems that the "tab windows" option was removed for the backend for some reason..

Comment: You are working in the back-end db, yesno? Are you using Access 2007/12 accdb? If so, you need to look at the Options, where this appearance is controlled.

Comment: BTW, maximized tables can be closed, but it takes a bit to find the x. It is at the top of the screen under the x that closes the application. And very confusing it is, too.

Comment: Using MSA2012, working in the backend. I'll take a look through those options (where might they be? I think it lies with the tabbing options.. it seems to be what was removed) but that X is handy enough! Thanks.

Comment: File->Options->Current Database under Document Windows Options

Comment: Ahha! That's exactly what I needed. Why on earth would MS decide to have that default for front-ends and not for back-ends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appearance of the windows in MS Access 2012 is controlled by the Options settings:

`File->Options->Current Database under Document Windows Options`